# How can I use .Contains() to get at a property of a collection using LINQ to Objects?

Tags: linq-to-objects

I have an IEnumerable of the following object:

```
public class Recipient  
{  
    public  int UserID { get; set; }
    public  string Name { get; set; }
}
```

So, I have an `IEnumerable<Recipient> Recipients`, and I'd like to do a .Contains() on Recipients.  Except, I'd like to do a .contains() on each recipients UserID, to see if my Recipients contain a particular userID.

If I just had an `IEnumerable<Int> Recipients`, it would be easy to do `Recipients.Contains(5);`

But, because I'm trying to get a property of the collection, how do I use Contains in that instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Recipients.Any(r => r.UserID == 5)
```

Alternatively, you can map the collection to a collection of `UserID` values and perform a `Contains` there:

```
Recipients.Select(r => r.UserID).Contains(5)
```